# p:commandButton does not fire action

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Here is the problem: actionlistener does not want to be fired

```
@ManagedBean(name="hotelsController")
@SessionScoped
   public class HotelsController implements Serializable {
      public void requestHotelAvail(ActionEvent event) {
         request = new Request(df.format(arrivalDate), df.format(departureDate));
      }
   }
```

and xhtml

```
<h:panelgroup id="rooms"/>
<h:form  id="hotelSearch">
            <p:commandButton actionListener="#{hotelsController.requestHotelAvail}" value="submit" update="rooms" />
</h:form>
```

I have tried everything I could search of changed `@managedbean` to `@component` set `import` to `import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;`

But it still does not fire anything.

Form is in a `p:accordion` and when used with `h:commandbutton` it works fine

**EDIT**: sorry for mislead. rooms updates after click but actionListener is not fired. so rooms will not get any new data. Important code in `requestHotelAvail` needs to be fired before updating rooms and its not.

**EDIT2**: `PrimeFaces 2.2.1` - I've read whole manual to primefaces but theres no explanation to this as I've done all that it states

I've tried using `action` instead of `actionListener` without `ActionEvent` but it never do anything. using `<h:commandbutton action="#{hotelscontroller.requestHotelAvail}"/>` works great but I want that ajax engine to refresh only that `rooms` panelgroup

**UPDATE**: Now it works. Form couldn't be in `<p:accordion>` but why and how to enable it there? Form now I'll work without it.

Comment: With "does not fire anything" do you actually mean 1) The method is not invoked (as confirmed by a debugger, logger or sysout), or 2) The `rooms` panelgroup is not updated?

Comment: Does not resolve your problem but is a good practice to have the form component above all the other components as long as it doesn't interfere with other forms (avoid also inner forms)

Comment: Also, put some `sysout's` in that method to be sure or create another method in that class... in server log doesn't appear anything? Like could not find the bean, or action/property not found? If you use Netbeans be sure your class is correctly built...

Comment: What PrimeFaces version? Try `action` instead of `actionListener` and remove that `ActionEvent` argument which you aren't using anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect the different behavior from h:commandLink comes from ajax/non-ajax processing.

By default - if you don't use f:ajax - h:commandLink is non-ajax and entire page is rerendered. Primefaces p:commandLink is using ajax and you indicate rooms as component to be updated. In your case rooms is outside form so it should rather be addressed as :rooms (mind the colon) instead of just rooms.

update: have you tried ajax with h:commandLink? It would be:

```
<h:commandButton action="#{hotelscontroller.requestHotelAvail}" value="submit">
  <f:ajax render=":rooms"/>
</h:commandButton>
```

Also I'm not that familiar with primefaces but maybe you can try to explicitly indicate the component to process with additional `process="@this"` - although I would assume this to be default as in basic library.

Comment: I'm not using h:commandLink and the problem is not about the `update` but the `actionListener`. update Works Fine

Comment: well `<h:commandButton action="#{hotelscontroller.requestHotelAvail}" value="submit">
  <f:ajax render=":rooms"/>
</h:commandButton>`it now behaves as `<p:commandButton>` so panelgroup is updated but action is not fired. there has to be greater problem to managedBean or whole xhtml

Comment: Can you try to put is outside p:accordion? It sounds like an iterating component and these tend to be problematic.

Comment: Thank you that works like a charm but now i have to find out why and how to use it in `<p:accordion.`.

Comment: Please file an issue if you think this is a problem with p:accordion.

Answer (score 0):

You try to inspect the response:

Open **Chrome or Firefox -> Inspect Element -> Network** and follow the ajax call.

[image]